# Adding button to a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

i have next custom cells:

[image]

When i fill my table i do this:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
cell.iboPopImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[cell.iboPopImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

I add tap event to this little highlighted image.

And here is the function-event:

I want to pass cell index into it, so i could operate with a needed cell

```
-(void)tapDetected:(NSInteger *)index
{
    //Some code to do
}
```

But it doesn't allow me to write it like so:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:indexPath.row)];
```

How to fix it?

Comment: are you using custom cell?

Comment: yes i do use Custom cell

Comment: so it is a button right? you directly use button action. why you use tap gesture?

Comment: Quote from my question: "I add tap event to this little highlighted image."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a gesture recognizer you don't get to choose the format of the action method that it will call, the method should be:

```
- (void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
```

you can then use `sender` to get the view that was tapped on (and then maybe get its `tag`).

p.s. thats `@selector(tapDetected:)`

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to get it, In your interface:

```
@interface viewcontroller : UITableViewController
{
 int indexpathRow;
}

-(void) getIndex:(int)getRow;
```

then in your .m file, in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, call as `[self getIndex:indexPath.row];`.  and then get your index path:

```
-(void) getIndex:(int)getRow
{
indexpathRow = getRow;
}
```

Now you can use it anywhere in your viewController class.